# Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::getCollectionPersister() must be an array, null given

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

My entities look like this (pasting just relevant parts):

User.php

```
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Startup", inversedBy="members", cascade={"persist"})
     * @OrderBy({"name"="ASC"})
     * @var Startup[]
     */
    private $startups;

    public function __construct($data = array()) 
    {
        $this->startups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->joined = new DateTime("now");
        parent::__construct($data);
    }
```

Startup.php

```
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var User
     */
    private $founder = null;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="startups", cascade={"persist"})
     * @OrderBy({"lastName" = "ASC"})
     * @var User[]
     */
    private $members;

    public function __construct($data = array())
    {
        $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->topics = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();

        $this->founded = new DateTime("now");

        parent::__construct($data);
    }
```

Now with those I am running this code ($this->identity instanceof User, $values is just some struct filled with strings, $this->model is EntityManager):

```
          $startup = new Startup();
          $startup->name = $values->name;
          $startup->founder = $this->identity;
          $this->model->persist($startup);
          $this->identity->startups[] = $startup;
          $this->model->flush();
```

And I get this:

> Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::getCollectionPersister()
>   must be an array, null given, called in
>   .../libs/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 332 and defined

Triggered on flush obviously. What have I got wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `$data = array()` instead of `$data = null` in constructors?

Comment: Thats not issue, I got it covered, I already removed it from post to make it more clear. `if($data == null) $data = array();` is before I work with `$data`. But it is actually good point, I dont know why I used `null` as default value.

Comment: Are you able to:
 1. Provide a better stack trace (complete one, eventually with passed in parameters)
 2. tell us why your model has persistence methods?

Comment: Call stack is in the question now. Model is just helper class to make access to repositories and EM core methods easier.

Comment: @ZdeněkTopič can you now please try to run schema tool validation? It's a CLI tool. Not sure if it's integrated with Nette though.

Comment: Sorry, nothing is obvious.  You're going to have to brute force this one.  Try printing the various fields of startup and identity until you find the null.

Comment: Thanks for the validtion tool idea, helped me fix another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. `$this->identity` was problem. Framework got it serialized and then unserialized.

Comment: It was probably doing some weird serialization/unserialization/cloning magic :)

Comment: I think I know what happened, its all my bad. I forgot that it is loaded from EM directly only first time when logged id. Next time it is just serialized/unserialized object from sessions or other storage possibly. I am an idiot, I`ll persist it on every request automatically to keep using it as I meant.

Comment: That clears it :)

Remember to not serialize your entities, it is just liquid pain you're drinking.